# Less custom function/mixin

Tags: less, less-mixins

For example I have next less code

```
form.someForm
{
    .form-group
    {
        > div
        {
            @media @wideMobile
            {
                width: calc(~"100%-144px");            
            }
        }

        > label
        {
            @media @wideMobile
            {
                width: 138px;            
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to write something like

```
form.someForm
{
    .setWidths(138px,144px); 
}
```

To get the same result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess all those examples at [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features) could emanate a few ideas:

```
form.someForm {
    .setWidths(138px, 144px);
}

// the mixin:

.setWidths(@labelWidth, @divMargin) {
    .form-group {
        > div {
            @media @wideMobile {
                width: calc(100% ~'-' @divMargin);
            }
        }

        > label {
            @media @wideMobile {
                width: @labelWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or even shorter (if the descendants share same media query):

```
.setWidths(@labelWidth, @divMargin) {
    .form-group {
        @media @wideMobile {
            > div   {width: calc(100% ~'-' @divMargin)}
            > label {width: @labelWidth}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Could not have a chance to try. This is really working thank you very much. This is so nice to hide the knowledge of how it is structured.